# How to fix inet not showing after sometime permanently?

Tags: kali-linux, windows, virtualbox, networkmanager, ifconfig

```
┌──(root㉿kali)-[~]
└─# ifconfig                                                                                                                                        
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.25.209  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.25.255
        inet6 fe80::a35b:2f50:7fd4:bcef  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:00:00:00:00:11  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 22  bytes 2368 (2.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 30  bytes 4066 (3.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 4  bytes 240 (240.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4  bytes 240 (240.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`inet 192.168.25.209  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.25.255` line doesn't show after sometime. I have to restart network manager to fix it.
I'm using Oracle VM VirtualBox on a Windows 10 host.

After this log, above mentioned line disappears!:

```
Dec 25 22:03:33 kali NetworkManager[88036]: <info>  [1703522013.1961] dhcp4 (eth0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds) 
Dec 25 22:03:33 kali NetworkManager[88036]: <info>  [1703522013.2013] dhcp4 (eth0): state changed no lease
```

Comment: Check NetworkManager config and logs to find out why the IP address disappears.

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.

Comment: Kali is for advanced security researchers only. If this problem is something that you cannot even begin to diagnose, then clearly Kali is not for you. You are better off installing a more mainstream distro, and if you require some packages that Kali Kali has, then you can easily install them in another distro. Kali is not named after the hindu god.

Comment: @Bib ROFL. I know about god thing!

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should try this command after trying the commands @[walinator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/11135/waltinator) suggested: The command is: `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`, this command helps you restart only the Network Manager service, instead of restarting the entire network manager.